# Can't replace image src with JQuery dynamically using MySql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've tried a lot of things and running out of ideas. I'm trying to retrieve dynamically images taht I have stored in some folder, retrieving their path from the database, so they can be loaded following that provided path.

My view code;

```
<div class="card mb-4">
                <img id="artimg" src="" class="card-img-top" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]"/>
</div>
```

My JQuery:

```
$('#mark').change(function(event){
    var citid = $(this).val();
    window.console && console.log('sending $_POST');
    $.post('mod/imgart.php', {'idc':citid}, function(data){
      $("#artimg").attr("src", data);
      window.console && console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

My Model:

```
<?php
  require_once "../pdo.php";

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE mark_id = {$_POST['idc']}");
  echo"<img src=''/>";
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo"<img src='{$row['artic_image']}'/>";
};
```

*Note: I will use placeholders and take care of injections

I look into the console and the data is properly retrieved (... I tried also with images/chile/calle_yungay.png) but the image is not replaced on screen...please help!

Comment: *Note: you aren't using placeholders and "taking care of" injections. Don't start doing something the wrong way and then change it later. Do it right. It's one extra line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mod/imgart.php` outputs 2 full `img` elements. Remove the `<img src=''/>` outputs and only output the value that should go in the `src` attribute.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT artic_image FROM objects WHERE mark_id = ? limit 1");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['idc']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['artic_image']";
```

I've also parameterized for you. Additionally don't use `*` when you only want 1 column, and don't loop (`while`) when you only want 1 row (I also added `limit` to your query. If it is going to return more than 1 row you should return a JSON object and iterate over that in the JS. It is unclear how you would populate multiple image URLs though in that code.

Options 2 for multiple images:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT artic_image FROM objects WHERE mark_id = ? limit 1");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['idc']));
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     echo '<img src="' . $row['artic_image'] . '" />';
}
```

Then put the full list of images in the container like this (pseudo code, untested):

```
$('#mark').change(function(event){
     var citid = $(this).val();
     window.console && console.log('sending $_POST');
     $.post('mod/imgart.php', {'idc':citid}, function(data){
          $("#populate_me").html(data);
         window.console && console.log(data);
     });
});
```

Comment: thank you! I plan to iterate in the view later, using the retrieved values to generate a collection of images

Comment: That is the exact instance when you want to parameterize. As I wrote it should be correct. Assuming `$_POST['idc']` has the value.

Comment: Per your update, maybe then what you want to do is build full `img` elements in your PHP, then populate a `div` or container in your browser with the response.

Comment: @Rodrigo 
user3783243 is correct. 
You will have to eliminate issues one by one and debug your code line by line. Make sure the PHP receives the correct parameters (echo POST?) and make sure it sends (echos back) the correct intended value. See what does it return in your console when AJAX is triggered.

Comment: You also need to determine if your issue is Backend side issue or Frontend side issue. You can elemenicate PHP issue (proof it's a JS / frontside issue) if you hardcode the php responsce in a string variable and echo it as it is. If it does't work, then you have issue in building your HTML element. If it works fine, then it's you php echoing something wrong. As indicated, your php is echoing two, if not more, `<img>` elements and they will be placed in side **src=** `<img src= ""`

Comment: @user3783243  comments were very useful, thanks. Mohammed Joraid yep, I've been harcoding variables to see how data is actually sent, thanks. Now I'm trying to retrieve the data from the model, because it doent apear in my console.. an issue with the echo "{$row['tour_image']}"; part...